# Refactoring Nested If-Else Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, refactoring

could you help me give me some ideas how to refactor the following nested if-statement?

```
function priceCalculator(age, height) {

  if (age == "under 18") {
      if (height <= 1.5) {
          price = 6.18;
      } else if (height > 1.5 && height <= 1.8) {
          price = 5.59;
      } else if (height > 1.8) {
          price = 5.37;
      }
  } else if (age == "18-50") {
      if (height <= 1.5) {
          price = 7.38;
      } else if (height > 1.5 && height <= 1.8) {
          price = 6.19;
      } else if (height > 1.8) {
          price = 7.22;
      }
  } else if (age == "over 50") {
      if (height <= 1.5) {
          price = 8.48;
      } else if (height > 1.5 && height <= 1.8) {
          price = 8.53;
      } else if (height > 1.8) {
          price = 8.17;
      }
  }

  console.log(price);
}
```

It gets pretty ugly, once I introduce even more age and height categories. Is there a possibility to kind of shorten the code and make it prettier? Switch statements are problematic, because the second variable is an integer.

Comment: this doesn't make sense, u are returning the same price for every age category.

Comment: yes, sorry, I just adjusted the code so that it is easier to comprehend. But it should return different "prices"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case when the prices change for each age and height, start with an object indexed by age. Inside, for each age, you could have an array of height thresholds and their associated price. `.find` in the array the first matching threshold given the height, and return the associated price.

```
const config = {
    'under 18': [
        // [Height must be <= this, to get this price]
        [1.5, 6.18],
        [1.8, 5.59],
        [Infinity, 5.37]
    ],
    '18-50': [ // change as needed
        [1.5, 6.18],
        [1.8, 5.59],
        [Infinity, 5.37]
    ],
    // ...
}
function priceCalculator(age, height) {
    return config[age]
        .find(([threshold]) => height <= threshold)
        [1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. 

Can you tell me, how this approach is called, so I can research it a bit further?

Comment: I don't know if it's "called" anything, it's just something I came up with when I saw the question. Generally, if you have repetitive dynamic code, if you can put the parts that change into a single data structure instead, it'll be better to figure out how to construct and navigate that data structure.

Comment: Your code works. Unfortunately I haven't learned yet, how to use these thresholds, so I won't be bale to use it. `return data[Baualtersbereich].find(([test]) => qm <= test)[1];`

If you have any additional information on these, I'd love to read more about it.

Comment: See the `[Height must be <= this, to get this price]`. For example, `[1.5, 6.18]` means: if the height is below 1.5 (1.5 is the threshold), the price is 6.18. The first matching threshold-price pair is then found by the `.find` callback, and then the price is extracted from the pair and returned.

Comment: @VioJoe  Search for "object destructuring in javascript" in a search engine for more information about the `([threshold])` syntax used in the answer. MDN's article on ["destructuring assignment"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) does not explain the concept well.